# Can I use a single SMPS instead of 4 separate transformers?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Can I connect 4 nos car halogen bulbs (12 volts 90/ 100 watts each ) to a 12 volts smps which is 200 meters away ( cable size 6 sq mm copper)
If yes, what amps rating?

Also will the bulbs get more hotter than normal?

By normal I mean generally these lights run on car batteries

What would be the difference if I connect them to 4 different soft start transformers (12 volts 100 watts each ? Temperature wise, cost durability wise ) of course these transformers have to be near the bulbs say 5 to 8 meters

Comment: Four 100-W loads is going to require a 400 W supply, not 100 W.

Comment: @Sam 6mm² of Cu will have 4.72 ohms resistance there and back.  400W at 12V wants 33A.  33A x 4.72ohms = 157V drop.  Even if you run a separate cable for each bulb it would drop 39V and you only have 12 to start with.  No.  This will not work.

Comment: First you ask about connecting to a 12V SMPS, and then you switch to asking about transformers.  Do you mean SMPS both times?

Comment: Perhaps you should show a sketch of each of the two things you want to try, including the lengths and gauges of the wire you're proposing to use?

Answer (score 3):

> Can i connect 4 nos car halogen bulbs (12 volts 90/ 100 watts each )
>   to a 12 volts smps which is 200 meters away ( cable size 6 sq mm
>   copper) if yes what amps rating

Yes, you can. But the results won't be good.

Watts = volts x amps, so 100 watts / 12 volts = 8.33 amps. You have 4 bulbs so at 12 volts they would draw 8.33 x 4 = ~33 amps.

But that only applies when the bulbs get 12V. 6 mm<sup>2</sup> copper wire has a resistance of ~0.0029 Ω per meter. The round trip for 200 m is 400 m, so the wire resistance will be 0.0029 x 400 = 1.16 Ω. If the bulbs had fixed resistance then [Ohms's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) says they would be 12 / 8.33 = 1.44 Ω each and the circuit would look like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp8IXT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which is equivalent to this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYgWDl.png)</sup>

With the same current going through cable and bulbs the voltage would split proportionally to their resistances, and the bulbs would only get 12 x 0.361 / (1.16 + 0.361) = 2.85 volts. So they would be very dim. In practice an incandescent bulb has lower resistance at lower voltage because the filament is not as hot, so they would get even less voltage. This is obviously not satisfactory.

So what to do? You could run a separate 6 mm<sup>2</sup> cable to each bulb, but even then the voltage would drop to less than 7 volts at the bulb.

So you must either use much thicker cable, or a much higher voltage (which needs less current for the same power) and transform it down to 12V at the end of the cable. 400 watts at 110 volts AC only requires 400 / 110 = 3.6 amps, which would drop 3.6 x 1.16 = ~4.2 volts in your cable, less than 4% loss. You could use four 100 VA mains step-down transformers, or one 400 VA transformer, or a 12 Volt DC power supply with at least the same rating. A regulated DC power supply should output constant 12V even if the mains voltage varies.

> also will the bulbs get more hotter than normal

If the voltage is lower they will draw less power and run cooler. In a vehicle the battery voltage is closer to 14 volts when the motor is running, so they might 'normally' get a bit more than 12 volts and run hotter.